# Angular service constructor race

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication

I have an Angular application that has a data service

```
...

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  collectionEndpoint: string;
  counters: AngularFirestoreCollection<Counter>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private authService: AuthService) {
    this.collectionEndpoint = "users/" + this.authService.userData.uid + "/counters";
    this.counters = db.collection<Counter>(this.collectionEndpoint, ref =>
      ref.orderBy("name")
  );

  getCounters() {
  return this.counters.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions =>
      actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Counter;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      })
    )
  );
}

...

}
```

which has `AuthService` within its constructor. `AuthService` is as follows:

```
...

Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthService {
  userData: firebase.User;

  constructor(
    private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {
    this.angularFireAuth.authState.subscribe(userData => {
      if (userData) {
        this.userData = userData;
      }
    });
  }

...

}
```

Which is then accessed in a component

```
export class CounterDashboardComponent {
    counters: Observable<Counter[]>;

    constructor(private counterService: CounterService) {
      this.counters = this.counterService.getCounters();
    }

...

}
```

This is accessed in the html with `*ngFor="let counter of (counters | async)"`

When the page is refreshed (it enters the page correctly) on a route that uses `DataService` it tries to access `authService.userData.uid` (first line of constructor) before the authService has populated that property.

How can this be solved/avoided?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Move the call out of the constructor ?

Comment: By the call, I'm guessing you mean the call to populate `this.counters`. This data is used in the component html immediately and needs to be available on construction.

Comment: Move the `this.counters =...` in the component into a different lifecycle hook. Like maybe onInit.

Comment: That moves the issue from the constructor into `getCounters()` since it calls `snapshotChanges()` on an undefined `this.counters`.

Forgive the back and forth, I'm just still confused on how to solve the base issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was listening directly to an Observable within the `DataService` (initialized an observable with the Counters inside the constructor) from the component i.e. `*ngFor="let counter of (counterService.counters | async)`.

Many thanks to those who provided assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Currently given by your example theres no reason to create a new AuthService

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  collectionEndpoint: string;
  counters: AngularFirestoreCollection<Counter>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    angularFireAuth.authState.subscribe(userData => {
      this.collectionEndpoint = "users/" + userData.uid + "/counters";
      this.counters = db.collection<Counter>(this.collectionEndpoint, ref =>
        ref.orderBy("name"));
    })
  }
...
```

Comment: The property `this.counters` is used soon after by the html and then the `this.counters` property is undefined at runtime;

Comment: then update your HTML to handle the fact that it's an async call (hence the need for a subscription). by definition it's not going to be present immediately.

Comment: Angular handles the data being passed to the HTML template and will re-render the HTML when the counter data changes. if `counters` is undefined in the HTML its for a different reason.

I highly suggest walking through the angular tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial it covers most of this

Comment: I have updated the question with how it ends up being used on the front end. It is accessing the Observable asynchronously. But when `getCounters()` accesses the `this.counters` property, it does not yet exist.